# How overwrite default function of a field in odoo new api

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I have a field that call a function to get default value (in module project_forecast):

```
 def default_user_id(self):
    return self.env.user if ("default_user_id" not in self.env.context) else self.env.context["default_user_id"]

user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string="User", required=True,
                          default=default_user_id)
```

I create another module to inherit it and change default value of field user_id but it's not working without any error in log, how can I resolve this ?

```
def default_user_id(self):
    return False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're linking a method directly on field definition. So overriding the method isn't enough anymore. Just define the field `user_id` again with `default` as the only parameter and ofc your new method:

The original model:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    _name = "my.model"

    def default_user_id(self):
        return self.env.context.get("default_user_id", self.env.user)

    user_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='res.users', string="User", required=True,
        default=default_user_id)
```

The inherited model:

```py
class MyModelInherit(models.Model):
    _inherit = "my.model"

    def default_user_id(self):
        return self.env['res.users']

    user_id = fields.Many2one(default=default_user_id)
```

Comment: I resolved it by combine 2 answers: 
`user_id = fields.Many2one(default=lambda self: False)`

Answer (score 4):

> Please check this

```
user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='User',readonly=True, default=lambda self: self.env.user)
```